# Session Manager KDE config file

Tags: ubuntu, session, config, kde-plasma

Where can I find the Config file of the KDE Session manager.

I have to script that a programm will be excluded from the restoring session during the log in.

I know i can set this at the Session Manager in the System-Configuration, but i need the file behind this.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

For KDE4 it's at: *~/.config/ksmserverrc*

For Plasma 5 it's at: *~/.config/ksmserverrc*

---

PS: Easy to figure out with a bit of strace debugging:

```
strace -e open -f kcmshell5 kcmsmserver 2>&1 | grep $HOME
```